# File upload not working but not throwing any errors

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to upload allow file uploads in my MVC app but when I test it out the page simply refresh, does not show any errors, and does not upload the file so I am at a complete loos as to what is wrong.

View:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file">Filenname:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), filename);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Your form action is blank

Comment: @Jasen  I was following http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/ what should the form action be then? typically an action of "" means post to the same page which should be grabbed by the Index ActionResult

Comment: Jasen is correct. You need to specify where the action is going - nothing to do with BeginForm

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete your action would be "controller/action". In this case your action name is "Index" so you need to substitute in the controller name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<form action="Controller/Index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file">Filenname:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This worked with out the Controller so `action="Index"`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't actually tried it, but my guess is that it's because you are not using `Html.BeginForm` and you are using simply `<form>`.
Try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Upload",FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <input type="file" name ="file" id ="file"/>
    <input type="submit">
}
```